# Spring Mongo - set custom collection on entity implementing interfaces

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Given a mongo entity class :

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "#{ T(de.axa.services.ecm.contentmanagement.service.archivbearbeiten.util.ServiceUtils).getMongoCollectionPreFix() }_allgarchiv")
public class AllgArchivReference implements Kleinsparte {
```

My aim is to store this entity in an collection "xxx_allgarchiv" whereby "xxx" is based on the runtime environment.

I have one Crud repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ReferenceRepository extends MongoRepository<Kleinsparte, String> {
}
```

and the simple implementation....

```
    result = referenceRepository.save(kleinsparte);
```

No I want to store the AllgArchivReference in the collection above ("xxx_allgarchiv").
Unfortunately the entity is stored in a new created collection "kleinsparte" but this is not what i want.

How could I enforce spring data to store allgarchivReference in eponymous collection without creating a new own crud repository?
By the way, there more than 20 other Reference-Entities which are also implementing the interface "Kleinsparte" and i don't want to create for each entity an own crud repository interface.

Is this possible? Any help are really appreciate.

Kind regards,
Bodo

Comment: Try placing the `@Document` annotation on the interface `Kleinsparte` instead of the implementation class.

Comment: Hi prasad, as i mentioned there are about 20 Reference-Entities which implements the "Kleinsparte"-Interface. And additional to that all these Entities need to be stored in an own collection. So, your solution won't work if i have to consider this fact.

Comment: How is the collection name determined? It is determined dynamically by the runtime. Placing the annotation on the interface works; because the runtime determines the collection name based on the annotation - not the interface. And, the interface is implemented by all classes -based on which (class) the data to be stored in the collection is determined.

Comment: In the broadest sense the collections is determined during the process and depends on the concrete class "behind" the kleinsparten interface. It is not depend on any vm property or other stuff.

Comment: It's not a good solution. You may recicle `.save`, `.delete`, `.findById`, so on... but other queries won't work, since your `Kleinsparte` doesn't have all attributes for all sub-classes, so you need to define custom query per sub-class. Example: Foo class has attribute `foo` and Bar class has `bar` attribute. You need to write 2 interfaces to query items: `findOneByFoo` and `findOneByBar`

Comment: In my case the entities just have to be written. No queries against the collection will be done during the service. Just write commands.
Ok, as a summary I understand there is no chance to avoid the creation of one crud repository for every entity (which implements Kleinsparte).
Then i'll have over 20 crud repositories, one for each entity.

Comment: Not necessarily. Instead use [MongoTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial), you need to create single "repository / service" and define several methods which calls mongotemplate, and it will be compatible with all your entities. `CrudRepository` is thought for simple queries / use cases, but for more complete and flexible implementation, I recommend you to use `MongoTemplate`, which can perform CRUD + Aggregation queries

Comment: Hi Valijon, thank for the helpful tipp.  :-)
Now I use a custom repo with the insert command where I could deliver also the target collection.